# Content-Security-Policy error in google chrome extension making

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I am making a chrome extension that will open all links on a page in new tabs.

Here are my code files:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "A browser action which changes its icon when clicked.",
  "version": "1.1",
    "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ],
 "browser_action": {     
    "default_title": "links",      // optional; shown in tooltip
    "default_popup": "popup.html"        // optional
  },
 "content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "js": ["background.js"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Awesome Popup!</title>
    <script>
function getPageandSelectedTextIndex() 
  { 
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function (response) 
    { 
        console.log(response.farewell); 
    }); 
   }); 
        } 
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
        getPageandSelectedTextIndex(); 
});
         </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="getPageandSelectedTextIndex()">
      </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
    updateIcon();  

});
function updateIcon() {
  var allLinks = document.links;
  for (var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) {
    alllinks[i].style.backgroundColor='#ffff00';

}
}
```

Initially I wanted to highlight all the links on the page or mark them in some way; but I get the error "Refused to execute inline script because of Content-Security-Policy".

When I press the button inside the popup, I get this error: `Refused to execute inline event handler because of Content-Security-Policy`.

Please help me fix these errors, so I can open all links in new tabs using my chrome extension.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One of the consequences of `"manifest_version": 2` is that [Content Security Policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/) is enabled by default. And Chrome developers chose to be strict about it and always disallow inline JavaScript code - only code placed in an external JavaScript file is allowed to execute (to prevent [Cross-Site Scripting vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) in extensions). So instead of defining `getPageandSelectedTextIndex()` function in `popup.html` you should put it into a `popup.js` file and include it in `popup.html`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```

And `<button onclick="getPageandSelectedTextIndex()">` has to be changed as well, `onclick` attribute is also an inline script. You should assign an ID attribute instead: `<button id="button">`. Then in `popup.js` you can attach an event handler to that button:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function()
{
  document.getElementById("button")
          .addEventListener("click", getPageandSelectedTextIndex, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: Just beat me to it. Perfect answer and is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: This is so stupid. Who came up with this idea?! Now I have to change all my inline onclicks and put them in an external js file. And I have a bunch of files including them.

Comment: @Derek: It's a much better approach security-wise, lots of security issues happen because people aren't careful enough with `innerHTML` and such. Regardless of that, it seems that Chrome somewhat relaxed the content policy requirements in current Canary builds, `unsafe-inline` might now be supported as well.

Comment: @wladimir - hope they will relax the policy in he future!