# Google Chrome Extension and Content Security Policies

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm developing a Google Chrome Extension that makes use of an iframe.
Getting an error in the console when run as an Extension from Chrome but NO ERRORS when run as a local file or on github.

The app functions as it should as an extension (regardless of the error). I do understand that this is a content security policy violation. Is there a way around this or am I going about writing to the iframe incorrectly...

Please help. Thanks.

[raw file on github](https://rawgithub.com/craigwayne/nexus-prototype/alpha/chrome-extension/nexus-prototyper.html)

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Content-Security-Policy error in google chrome extension making](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045653/content-security-policy-error-in-google-chrome-extension-making)

Comment: nope, not a possible duplicate, i fully understand that you can't have inline scripts... but for some reason I was blind sided by the fact that I dynamically write inline script to the frame on the right. I'm not sure how to close this question... but whoever knows can freely close this question. there's no solution, i just understand what was producing the error now. peace