# call a function on chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am working with a chrome app and I developed it as a normal web page. It includes several .js files and also calls some functions on click and on load.

```
<body onload="thisIsOnLoadFunction()">

<button class='btn btn-info btn-large icon-undo pull-right' onclick='cancelAll()'>
```

They are some of them. But it does not work as normally when I run it as an app.

in console it shows an error saying

```
 Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following
 Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 
 chrome-extension-resource:".
 Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set,
 so 'default-src' is used as a fallback
```

How can I get that working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Content-Security-Policy error in google chrome extension making](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045653/content-security-policy-error-in-google-chrome-extension-making)

Answer (score 3):

You can not use inline event handler in apps. It is a security issue.

Include a JS file where you do something like:

```
document.getElementById("some_id").addEventListener("click", some_function);
```

or use *querySelector* attach event directly by *..ById("some_id").onclick* etc.

Typically wrap the code in:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  ....
});
```

---

As an extra note to adding event listeners.

If you need to pass arguments to a function there is various ways. One way is to use closures, another way which I find cleaner is to use *bind*. As this is for an app you do not need to vory about browser capabilities on bind.

Example:

```
function some_fun(i, e) {
    console.log(i); <-- This will be value of `i` in loop
    console.log(e); <-- This will be the event.
}

var p = document.getElementsByTagName('P'),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < p.length; ++i) {
    p[i].addEventListener("click", some_fun.bind(null, i));
}
```

Another very useful thing with *bind()* is the ability to pass context. For example:

```
function MyObj(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

var my_obj = new MyObj(42, 13);

someElem.addEventListener("click", my_fun.bind(my_obj));
```

When *someElem* now is clicked you can use things like *this.x* and get 42.

Comment: How can I call another function here. and get the return values.

Comment: @ddarz4u: Not sure what you mean. Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/cLn8b/